# Use by date on cacao butter

Tags: food-safety, chocolate, raw

I have just used cacao butter 6 yrs out of date to make raw chocolate adding honey and raw cocoa powder. I didn't realise until after I had made the chocolate how out of date it was. Is it OK to eat?  The cacao butter looked fine.  I had it in the fridge all that time in a sealed plastic container.

Comment: By 'out of date' do you mean it's past its "Use By" or past it's "Best Before"?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't eat it if I were you. I don't think it is safe to eat if it is 6 years out of date. I recommend you to throw it and make another one with new ingredients.

Comment: Your statement may or may not be correct. It is customary here to find some references to back up anything you claim. Do you have any  links to sources?